# chart js : GridLine don't show on Barchart

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, silverstripe

I work on SilverStripe 4 and usign Chart js (barchart) and the gridLine is don't show. here my code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("plradar").getContext("2d");

var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'radar',
data: data,
options: {
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Degre'
        },
        scale: {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            stepSize: 1
        },
          pointLabels: {
            fontSize: 12
        }
        },
        elements: {
            point: {
                radius: 3
            }
        }
    }
});
```

as the result

[image: the barchart]

Can someone advise how to change my code?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. SS4 is still in alpha status, so there might be problems. But i doubt your problem is really related to SilverStripe.  Do you see anything in your browser's console? Any debug messages?

Comment: Not sure if understood, do you expect that this code will draw a barchart? In that case, you shouldn't specify `type: 'radar'`.

Comment: From the docs http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-common-configuration it should be `scales:`, not *scale* in the options.